# React Native bottom bar change background color when screen is focused

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

How can I change the background color of tab bar item when the screen is focused. I am using `react-navigation` version 6.x. Here is my code snippet for the bottom bar

```js
<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Main"
        activeColor={colors.yellow}
        inactiveColor={colors.white}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={Main}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Countries"
          component={Countries}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <Icon name="ios-globe" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="GlobalCasesScreen" component={GlobalCasesScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do that:

```js
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: "blue",
  }}
>
```

You can replace `"blue"` with any color you want.

For more information about `BottomTabNavigator`, check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbaractivebackgroundcolor)